# Strange Message body bytes size for rabbitmq

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I'm using rabbitmq and facing some heap space problems on java client. Normally theses messages are quite small on size, but sometimes I fall in this situation that with only 2K messages the Message body bytes is over 8.8GB.  In my tests I already let this exactly same queue with 200K messages and the message body bytes is not bigger than 200MB.

[image]

another scenario, same queue same kind of message but totally different pattern

[image]

Anyone can help me understand what can makes this message get bigger than normal?

Comment: there is currently no question in your post

Comment: thank you. My point is , what happens  to make this message body bytes that big.